# Adding data in one list from another list saves reference of first list

Tags: c#, list, reference, observablecollection

I have 2 observablecollection type list in which one list already contains data and in second list I am adding data from first list. But when I shuffle data in second list it also shuffles the data in first list.

First I tried to add data manually by using foreach loop

```
foreach(var dat in list1){        
    list2.add(new model(){
    name=dat.name
    });
}
```

then used this method to copy data.

```
list2 = new ObservableCollection<Model>(list1);
```

but nothing works for me

Here is my code which I am currently using

```
list1 and 2 are property of 
ObservableCollection<Model> type

list2 = new ObservableCollection<Model>(list1);
```

to shuffle data in list2

```
var templist = list2.Select(c => c).ToList();
templist.Shuffler();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            list2[i].name = templist[j].name;
            list2[i].Id = i + 1;
            j++;
        }
```

after this code the data in list1 is also shuffled.

What I want is whenever I shuffle data it should not affect data in my main list i.e. list1

Comment: clone the list : list2 = new ObservableCollection<Model>(list1.Select(x => x.Clone()));

Comment: Thanks @jdweng It worked with Clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jdweng for letting me know about **Clone**.

To make it work Correctly I need to implement ICloneable interface in my model.

Here is the good example of ICloneable implementation
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/important-interface-in-net-work-with-icloneable-interface/

Then I have used

```
 list2 = new ObservableCollection<Model>(list1.Select(c=>(Model)c.Clone()));
```

and it worked without any problem